# To get debug outputs on client - spmd

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, spmd

I am running a parallelized code courtesy the MATLAB Parallel Computing Toolbox using the spmd command. Specifically, the code is like this:

```
spmd
    out = function(data,labindex);
end
```

Now the function involves a library (libsvm) which gives me a trained classifier for each iteration. During the training process, there are several debug messages being printed out to the standard output by the library and somehow these are not appearing on my standard terminal - I think this is because the workers are actually on a cluster and hence the debug messages are not visible to me.

Is there anyway to reroute the debug messages ? (possibly other than writing to a file on a shared disk)

Comment: I assume your function `function` is not actually called that. Are you able to edit it's internals where the debug messages are printed? Or is the printing occurring inside compiled code? Are you actually using a cluster or is this computation being done just on your machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option may be to try the [Parallel Command Window](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel-command-window.html). This opens a new special Command Window with one pane per lab. You'll need to run commands from the "P>>" [`pmode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/pmode.html) prompt in this window. More [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/interactive-parallel-development.html).

Comment: That's a neat way to see the processing going on in the workers. Thanks!